# How to downgrade to Passenger 2.2.15?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I am using Passenger 3.0.5. For some reasons, I want to downgrade to Passenger 2.2.15. Is there any convenient way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, uninstall passenger 3.0.5 using the gem uninstall command and then install version 2.2.15.

```
gem uninstall passenger
gem install passenger -v 2.2.15
```

You can then proceed to [install the apache or nginx modules or simply use the standalone version of passenger](http://www.modrails.com/install.html).

Comment: Glad I could help. Be sure to mark the question as answered :)